# Update in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table say 
T1(col1,col2,col3,col4)

Now say column 2 is having varchar value. 
Requirement : It should always have 11 digits.

There are values whoes length range from 5 to 11 digits.

Depending on length of value already present in table for col2, i need to prefix zeros(0's) to the digit.

For eg, if value is 12345 i need to update it as 00000012345 and so on.

Please suggest. ALso if possible let me know cursor for this Update staement for multiple rows of a table with multiple cases (based on length).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
update T1
set col2 = RIGHT('000000'+col2,11)
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 11)
+ CAST(Col2 AS VARCHAR(11)), 11) Col2
FROM T1

Hope this might help.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
Update SomeTable set SomeColumn = replicate('0',11 - data_length(SomeColumn)) + SomeColumn
Where blah blah blah
```

should do it

See no need for cursor at all.